# Queries regarding RestAssured

Tags: java, spring, rest, integration-testing, rest-assured

Recently I've made use of RestAssured for testing Rest API and it seems to be pretty useful.
However I've a query regarding testing rest end-points. We don't deploy our services locally onto a server.
We write the unit test and integration tests and test it and deploy it on a separate dev1 environment.
What I want is to write an integration test that will post a request and test the rest-endpoint using restassured.Kindly advise. Thanks.

P.S. We don't have local server where we can deploy and hit the rest end-point.

Comment: May be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36283606/restassured-testing-without-running-tomcat

Answer (score 0):

Local or remote server doesn't matter I hope. Pls take a look at docs https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage

Answer (score -1):

You can set the remote server URL globally for all tests using `RestAssured.baseURI="<BaseURL>"` or you can pass the full URL in RestAssured method itself like `get("http://baseURL/service1")`

Comment: It is better to declare the URLs for the diffent tests inside the test classes in a string variable and use them in case of the different HTTP methods (get/post/put/delete).